# FreeNAS and AD authentication on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, truenas

Has anyone successfully used AD authentication using the latest version of FreeNAS with Windows 2008 R2 domain controllers? I wanted to use FreeNAS to host files and share them via CIFS but I couldn't make FreeNAS authenticate with a Windows 2008 R2 domain controller. Ultimately, the new CIFS shares will be referenced in the DFS namespace that we already have running on Windows 2008 R2 servers.

Any tip you can share with me?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the way NAS tries to authenticate to AD, can you check if there are any errors in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

The following are my settings:

- Domain Controller Name: DC1
- Domain Name: lab.local
- Netbios Name: nas
- Workgroup Name: lab
- Allow Trusted Domains: YES (tick)
- Administrator Name: administrator
- make sure nas has a fully qualified domain name
- make sure nameservers are set correctly

System Information
Hostname: nas.lab.local

Another quick gotcha if you follow the logs is time. Clock skew is not your friend.

I feel things slow down a lot after adding AD to freenas.

I just went to check CIFS settings and basically taking minutes same with changing permissions on datasets. This only started after adding AD.

I find permissions are better set in the shell of freenas. If you follow forums someone called protosd adds a lot of comments/help.

They have a website @ http://protosd.blogspot.co.nz/2011/12/protosds-unofficial-freenas-8-faq.html

Comment: Regarding the slow down - did you ever get to the bottom of this? We've just put our freenas on AD and everyone is complaining IIS responses are slow

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do it (in FreeNAS, you must use the pre-win2000 domain name. For example if your domain name is ‘freenas.org’, you must set the domain name ’FREENAS’)

*Access:Active Directory*
[Source](http://freenas.org/documentation:setup_and_user_guide:user_management)